# Trigger changing the function on XR Interaction Toolkit on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openxr

Normally, my triggers of the VR Controller are used for walk and look, but when i grab some interactable, the trigger doesn't work with the normal function, it starts to rotate and change the position of the interactable. How do I disable this function?

I looked all the Xr Grab Interactable but didn't find nothing